# avoid duplicated jQuery code?

Tags: javascript, jquery, carousel, bootstrap-modal

I am a novice to jquery. I have a section with some items. on click over any item i want to open the modal form, so instead of creating multiple modal forms i created one modal and than using carousel inside it to go through the items.

Now if one clicks the 10th item i want to apply the carousel active class to the 10th item. For now i have given id to all of them and using following code for each item. But that is not a good approach.

I appreciate your help!

Thanks

```js
     $('.filtr-item .mod1').on('click',function(){
        $('#menuCarousel').find('.active').removeClass('active');
        $('.mod1_item').addClass('active');
      });

      $('.filtr-item .mod2').on('click',function(){
        $('#menuCarousel').find('.active').removeClass('active');
        $('.mod2_item').addClass('active');
      });

      $('.filtr-item .mod3').on('click',function(){
        $('#menuCarousel').find('.active').removeClass('active');
        $('.mod3_item').addClass('active');
      });
```

Comment: put some html code, to work around

Comment: share your html so that we can understand it clearly

Comment: for the snippet to work, please put in an example html! This one throws an error!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a generic class and add a data-attribute

```js
$('.filtr-item .mod').on('click', function() { // or just $('.filtr-item').on 
  $('#menuCarousel').find('.active').removeClass('active');
  $('.' + $(this).attr("data-mod") + '_item').addClass('active');
});
```

```css
.active {
  color: red
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul>
  <li class="filtr-item"><a class="mod" data-mod="mod1">Activate Mod1</a></li>
  <li class="filtr-item"><a class="mod" data-mod="mod2">Activate Mod2</a></li>
  <li class="filtr-item"><a class="mod" data-mod="mod3">Activate Mod3</a></li>
</ul>

<hr/>

<div id="menuCarousel">
  <div class="mod1_item">Mod1</div>
  <div class="mod2_item">Mod2</div>
  <div class="mod3_item">Mod3</div>
</div>
```

For a longer explanation why to use `$(this).attr("data-mod")` rather than        `$(this).data("mod")`, please see comments and [jQuery Data vs Attr?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7261619/jquery-data-vs-attr)

---

UPDATE: If you cannot change the html, you will need to interrogate the class

```js
var re = /\bmod(\d+)/; // finds modN 
$('.filtr-item a').on('click', function() {
  $('#menuCarousel').find('.active').removeClass('active');
  var match = this.className.match(re),
    num = (match) ? match[1] : "";
  if (num) $('.mod' + num + '_item').addClass('active');
});
```

```css
.active {
  color: red
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul>
  <li class="filtr-item"><a class="mod1">Activate Mod1</a></li>
  <li class="filtr-item"><a class="mod2">Activate Mod2</a></li>
  <li class="filtr-item"><a class="mod3">Activate Mod3</a></li>
</ul>
<hr/>
<div id="menuCarousel">
  <div class="mod1_item">Mod1</div>
  <div class="mod2_item">Mod2</div>
  <div class="mod3_item">Mod3</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I am not wrong you want to use one function instead of three different function you are using. you can give a custom data field to html eg. data-demo= "mod1".

and use the below code:

```
$('.filtr-item').on('click',function(){
    $('#menuCarousel').find('.active').removeClass('active');
    $('.'+$(this).attr('data-demo')+'_item').addClass('active');
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

[JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/shree/my5oyz0s/1/)

Without `Data mode` you can try this way.

```
$('.filtr-item').on('click', function() {
   var num = $(this).prop('class').split(' ')[1].split('mod')[1];
   $('#menuCarousel').find('.active').removeClass('active');
   var cls = ".mod" + num + '_item';
   $(cls).addClass('active');
 });
```